# whatsapp://send?text not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, whatsapp

```
<div class="wp sb-icon"> 
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text From 
<?php
$n=$_GET['by'];
echo "*$n*"
?>
&#10;

%20Created%20Something%20Special%20Only%20For%20You%20Touch%20The%20Blue%20Line 
<?php echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" 
        target="_blank" title="Share this post on Whatsapp" class="whatsapp"> 
        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i> Whatsapp 
    </a> 
</div>
```

I am trying open WhatsApp app in a phone but it's not working through Chrome

Comment: It would make it easier to diagnose what the problem may be if you provide more context. Can you explain what you mean when you say it doesn't work e.g add the error that gets displayed, describe the behaviour that occurs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you need to url encode all that is part of the URL. I am not sure what

`<?php echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>`

is supposed to do, perhaps you can show the expected end result ?

```html
<?php $n=$_GET['by']; 
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>
<div class="wp sb-icon"> 
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text%20From<?=*$n*?
    ?>%0A%20Created%20Something%20Special%20Only%20For%20You%20Touch%20The%20Blue%20Line%0A<?= $actual_link ?>" 
        target="_blank" title="Share this post on Whatsapp" class="whatsapp"> 
        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i>Whatsapp</a> 
</div>
```